# How can I use httpUrlConnection with glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I want to use its various methods like setRequestMethod, setRequestProperty

**Here is the piece of code which I need to implement it using glide library instead of async task**

Thanks in advance.

```
public class ImageLoadingAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Void> {
        Bitmap bmp;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pb_imageProgressBar.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Integer... integers) {

            String url = PrefManager.getInstanceUrl()
                    + "clients/"
                    + integers[0]
                    + "/images?maxHeight=120&maxWidth=120";
            Log.d("ashu",url);
            try {
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) (new URL(url))
                        .openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(MifosInterceptor.HEADER_TENANT,
                        "default");
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty(MifosInterceptor.HEADER_AUTH,
                        PrefManager.getToken());
                httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/octet-stream");
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                httpURLConnection.connect();
                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
            }
            return null;
        }


        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (bmp != null) {
                iv_clientImage.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } else {
                iv_clientImage.setImageDrawable(
                        ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));
                pb_imageProgressBar.setVisibility(GONE);
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: If you are using glide then you do not need to do this. Am I missing something here?

Comment: @AshwaniK url enough wont work [link](https://demo.openmf.org/fineract-provider/api/v1/clients/11/images?maxHeight=120&maxWidth=120) check out the link which we get from string url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need HttpUrlConnection if you use Glide, just call Glide directly.

```
String url = PrefManager.getInstanceUrl()
                    + "clients/"
                    + integers[0]
                    + "/images?maxHeight=120&maxWidth=120";

GlideUrl glideUrl = new GlideUrl(url, new LazyHeaders.Builder()
                .addHeader((MifosInterceptor.HEADER_TENANT, "default")
                .addHeader(MifosInterceptor.HEADER_AUTH, PrefManager.getToken())
                .addHeader("Accept", "application/octet-stream")
                .build());
Glide.with(getActivity()).load(glideUrl).into(iv_clientImage);
```

Comment: hi @hakim the string url transforms into: https://demo.openmf.org/fineract-provider/api/v1/clients/11/images?maxHeight=120&maxWidth=120 and when called upon gives the following error message: **Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Fri Oct 07 13:10:24 UTC 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
No tenant identifier found: Add request header of 'Fineract-Platform-TenantId' or add the parameter 'tenantIdentifier' to query string of request URL.  **

Comment: @TOP_GUN007 because the image path is invalid, please make sure the image path is valid, you can test it by open the path in your web browser

Comment: I got the url using (log.d ) and its working fine in the app with proper authentication.

Comment: @TOP_GUN007 sorry, I didn't read your code properly before. now I update my answer by adding header to glide request. please test, I hope now it can work

Comment: thanks for being so helpful..I'll get back to you as soon as I implement it.